# Reset the Identity column value to zero in sybase

Tags: sybase

I have a table with the identity column.  It has 100 rows.  I truncated the table.  Now if i insert the new records having the identity value of 101,etc..  Can some one tell me how to reset the identity to Zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL you'll need is:

```
sp_chgattribute TABLENAME, "identity_burn_max", 0, "0"
```

Where `TABLENAME` is the name of your table obviously.  If you want to set it to something other than 0 then adjust the value of the last parameter.

Note also that if there are any rows currently in the table then you won't be able to set the value to anything less than the largest current value in that column.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible without being sa?